# Proving existence of an interval that satisfies these properties.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I had a quick question that has defeated me.

We let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be measurable that has a finite but nonzero measure. We want to show that there is a number $a_0  > 0$ so that for any $a$ with $0 < a < a_0$ there is a closed interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(I)=a$ and $m(S \cap I) = a/2$.

Now, my first instinct when seeing this is maybe applying the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem. But I am not sure what to define my function as. My brother (who sent me this problem) says to set $f_a(x) = m(S \cap [x,x+a])$.

Any help/hints are deeply appreciated.

Krull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand on the hints I gave below.

The Lebesgue differentiation theorem implies there exists $x_0\in S$ and $a_0>0$ such that

$$\frac{m([x_0,x_0+a]\cap S)}{a} >\frac{1}{2},$$

for $0<a<a_0.$ We can write the above as $m([x_0,x_0+a]\cap S) >\dfrac{a}{2}.$

Fix any such $a.$  Define $f_a:[x_0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ by setting $f_a(x)=$ $m([x,x+a]\cap S)$ for $x\ge x_0.$ Then $f_a$ is continuous and $f(x_0)>a/2.$ Since $f_a(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty,$ there exists $x$ such that $f_a(x)=a/2$ by the IVT. For this $x$ we have $m([x,x+a]\cap S)=a/2.$ Thus $I=[x,x+a]$ is the desired interval for this $a.$

---

Earlier post, hints: Your idea about the Lebesgue differentiation theorem might come in handy. Note also i) For $a>0,$ $f_a(x)=m([x,x+a]\cap S)$ is a continuous function of $x.$ ii) Since $m(S)<\infty,$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}f_a(x)=0.$

Comment: Firstly thank you for your comment. Could you elaborate a bit more on how $f_a(x)$ is continuous, I get stuck on trying to bound $\frac{1}{a}|m([x,x+a]\cap S) - m([y,y+a]\cap S)|$ ...

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but I am having a hard time seeing how (i) and (ii) would help me solve this. Could you provide a bit more, I apologize.

Comment: @WolfgangKrull I've sketched a proof using the hints I gave previously. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the steps except how you used LDT. I am familiar with the LDT statement but I am not sure how using it implies the first equation. Also, I am still confused why the function $f_a$ is continuous. I apologize if this is trivial, but could you help me understand this a bit more.

Comment: If $g$ is bounded and measurable, then $x\to \int_x^{x+a} g$ is continuous. In fact it is Lipschitz. Whatever proof you know for $g$ bounded and continuous will work here. For LDT here, look up "point of density". The idea for our problem is to choose $g=\chi_Q$ and apply LDT to that. My $x_0$ is a point of density.