# Continuity/limit of the following function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Basically, we have a measurable set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $0<m(S)<\infty$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Now if we define the function $f_a(x) = m(S \cap [x,x+a])$ then it is supposed to be continuous and the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is supposed to be $0$. Ultimately I want to answer this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123789/proving-existence-of-an-interval-that-satisfies-these-properties), but I am failing to see how the hints given there are true and how they help solve the problem.

BTW I am very thankful for the user who took time out of their day to point me in the right direction!!!

Now as for what I did, note that we can write $f_a(x) = m(S \cap[x,x+a]) = \int_x^{x+a} \mathbb{1}_S$. I thought from here I would be able to someone deduce the continuity but unfortunately, it led me nowhere.

Any help is much appreciated.

Krull.

Comment: Please avoid comments like "I have a quick and perhaps simple question". They are most of the time false and destroy the answerer's merit in advance.

Comment: Of course, I apologize I mean no disrespect.

Comment: I know, just a piece of warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_a(x)=g_a(x)-h_a(x)$ where $g_a(x)=m(S\cap (-\infty, x+a])$ and $h_a(x)=m(S\cap (-\infty, x))$. It is enough to prove that $g_a$ and $h_a$ are both continuous. Note that $0 \leq g_a(x)-g_a(y)=m(S\cap (y+a,x+a]) \leq  m(y+a,x+a])=x-y$ if $y <x$. Can you now complete the proof of continuity of $g_a$? The proof for $g_a$ is similar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But do you mean it is enough to prove that $g_a$ and $h_a$ are continuous?

Comment: Also, do you have any input on why the limit of the function is $0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @WolfgangKrull I have corrected the typos.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the continuity is very clear to me now! Do you have any advice for the other statement?

Comment: @WolfgangKrull Apply MVT to $f_a$. There exists $x$ such that $m([x,x+a]\cap S)=\frac a  2$.

Comment: Is this in regards to $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_a(x)$? Because your comment actually seems to answer my question that I linked in the post, it can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123789/proving-existence-of-an-interval-that-satisfies-these-properties).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote MVT for IVP in previous comment. The limit of $f_a(x)$ is $0$ since $[x,\infty)$ decreases to empty set. Take $a_0$ to be the maximum of $f_a$. IVT shows that the interval $I$ we are seeking can be taken in the form $[x,x+a]$. @WolfgangKrull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123788/discussion-between-wolfgang-krull-and-kavi-rama-murthy).